# How to configure OTB in my own application?

Tags: installation, orfeo-toolbox, osgeo4w

I had installed  [Orfeo Toolbox](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/SoftwareGuidech2.html) via Osgeo4w and using the applications through commandline.

Now my question is if i want to use [Orfeo Toolbox](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/SoftwareGuidech2.html)in my application without installing through Osgeo4w, and use the OTB applications through the command line ?

How to do it? I mean with out installing through Osgeo4w if i want to use the OTB applications through command line what are the dependencies  i need to download? how to configure ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I suggest also to compile OTB from source to be able to create your own program using OTB API. Assuming that you're working on a Windows lpatform, uou can find instructutions and useful scripts to build OTB on this system. Note that in that case you'll use OSGeo4W to install easily dependencies.

http://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/Windows_Build

Don't hesitate to ask questions on the otb-users mailing list if you've got some problems:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/otb-users

Regards,

Manuelm

Answer (score 0):

You can either install the binary packages or compile it from sources (then you need at least GDAL (and FLTK for visualization if needed) + a compiler such as Visual Studio express 2010). See [here](http://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/SoftwareGuide/SoftwareGuidech2.html) for more details. Note that you can also have access to OTB from QGIS using the sextante plugin, and there is also a nice wrapper for Python. By the way, you can use OTB through command lines when you install it using OSGEO4W, so why is it a problem.

Comment: Yeah through OSGEO4W it is fine. if i want to add it to my apllication. i mean suppose if i dont want to use through Osgeo4w or Qgis etc. how can i use them? i want to orthorectification so in my program if i want to use the system commands how can i do?

Comment: when you install it with OSGEO, you can use it as command lines. If you want your own program, then you need to build it from source. Otherwise, you can also use the GUI of OTB (Monteverdi). Could you add more details about your "program" by editing the question ?

Comment: program in the sense i had to add orthorectification feature to the GIS(developed by the team i am working).

Comment: Then I would suggest that you build it from the source. In the process, you will be asked for the missing dependencies, which can all be installed using OSGEO4W, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

Use OTB xdk!. It is allows you to easily get away with tailoring all otb dependencies without caring for each version X.Y.Z. And the best of all, it works as a standalone binary without conflicting with other packages. i.e. If you already have gdal,libtiff etc.. installed otb xdk won't conflict with them!. This guarantee is provided by xdk.

xdk == libs+headers for all dependencies of OTB.

you need to have a working cmake and gcc 4.x
OTB has xdk for windows, linux and osx.

https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/OTB_development_on_Windows
https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/OTB_development_on_Linux

PS: even though this is not a "one click" installer or setup. This is how easy you can get given the list of dependencies of OTB
https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/OTB_development_on_MacOSX

Files can be downloaded from here:
https://www.orfeo-toolbox.org/packages/xdk/OTB-5.9/